# Error trying to save new table to MySQL with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

Hi does somebody has any troubleshooting ideas to solve this problem?

I have a standard python-sql connection at my local machine:

`from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

`engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:*******@localhost/my_DB")`

`con = engine.connect()`

this DB consists of 200+ tables where I store stock/market information and I need to update it daily, in order to do that I usually construct a loop through all the tables to fetch up to date information from yahoo_finance using pandas datareader.

Once loaded into a new DF I use

`df_new.to_sql(name = stock_ticker, con = con, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)`

to save the new table into my DB.

The code above works just fine when I execute one by one, but when I try to implement the same idea on a loop it just breaks, sometimes on the very first instance of the loop:

`for stock in Stocks:`

`df_new = yahoo_quote(stock)`

`df_new.to_sql(name = stock_ticker, con = con, if_exists = 'replace', index = False)`

My first thought was that somehow I was exhuasting my machine/sql with so many calls, so I tried to add a time.sleep(5) and make sure I erased all the information from memory on each instance, but none of that seems to work. And, as I said, sometimes the computer just breaks on the very first loop.

By "break" I mean that it just keeps running forever without saving the table, usually it takes little less than 1 second to save a table, but when this happens I can leave it running for 10+ minutes and it still won't save it.

Comment: Perhaps try using a context manager inside your `for stock in Stocks:` loop, like [this](https://pastebin.com/XFj6h5Px).

Comment: If I understood it right that would create (begin) a new connection on each loop and not just use a Global one for all... I'll give it a shot! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`if_exists= 'replace'` option is drop the table before inserting new values. [API reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
your code repeats drop and create same Table in the loop.
If you want to replace all data, first time call `df_new.to_sql` set `if_exists= 'replace'`, and second time call set `if_exists= 'append'`.